# Get current devise user in extended classes in rspec support file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my rails app I use devise for user authentication. I also use i18n for the whole website and each user has the possibility to choose her or his specific language in the user settings. If the user browses the website with that given locale set, or it is a guest and the default locale is used, I don't want that locale to be shown in the url.

Here's an example:

A guest uses the english (default) version so the url is something like "anything.com/users/42", but if she or he changes to french (not permanently in the settings, but by clicking a link to the french version for example), the url changes to "anything.com/fr/users/42". If that user is logged in and has chosen french as the default language it's the other way around.

This is realized by the following lines in my `application_controller`

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def default_locale
  current_user ? current_user.locale : I18n.default_locale
end
helper_method :default_locale

def default_url_options options={}
  (I18n.locale.to_s.eql?(default_locale.to_s) ? { locale: nil } : { locale: I18n.locale }).merge options
end
```

This works flawless in my app.

But I have a problem when testing. In some tests I have expressions like this for an existing model named `League`:

```
visit edit_league_path(@league)
expect(page.current_path).to eq league_path(@league)
```

to check for redirections. The action `edit` for leagues is only allowed to admins.

Because I'm using devise I have logged in a user (who is not an admin) before with the following method:

```
# spec/support/controller_macros.rb
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user *user_roles
    before(:each) do
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, *user_roles)
      user.confirmed_at = Time.zone.now
      user.save
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

The factory for users creates random users with random locales.

I also have a support file, that fixes the localization for rspec tests, since the `default_url_options` from the `application_controller` are ignored in the rspec tests (as discussed [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255#issuecomment-2865917)):

```
# spec/support/fix_localization.rb
# workaround, to set default locale for ALL spec
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options options={}
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options options={}
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

Now my problem is, that when a logged in user with the default i18n locale set (e.g. `en`), visits the edit page of a league, gets redirected, since she or he is not allowed to visit that page. The redirection considers the `default_url_options` method from the `application_controller` and does not redirect to `/en/leagues/42` (as the test expects), but to `/leagues/42`.

My solution to this problem would be to change the `default_url_options` method in `spec/support/fix_localization.rb` to the same as in the `application_controller`, but I can't access the current user in the support files.

Has anyone an idea on how to access the current user or another idea or workaround for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution without duplicating the code. I just changed my `spec/support/fix_localization.rb` file to:

```
# spec/support/fix_localization.rb
# workaround, to set default locale for ALL spec
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options options={}
    subject.default_url_options options
  end
end
```

So now, the `default_url_options` method from the currently used controller (`subject`) which is inherited from the `ApplicationController` is used.

This technically does not answer my question but solves the underlying problem. To get the current user (as asked originally), one could use `subject` as well:

```
subject.current_user
```

But this is only available in support files, where the subject is a controller.